# dynamically create table statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how to dynamically create a table with same columns as that of previous table. in sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * into new_table from table where 1 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`select * into new_table from table`

Thats works in SQL2005

Comment: thanks for your reply, i need to create oly the table with the entire columns and not the datas. the fresh datas has to be into the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both of the above answers will work, but since you don't need the data and you just need the format, I would do the following:

select * into new_table from table

TRUNCATE new_table; -- I'm sure you know this, but just in case someone is new and doesn't, truncate leaves the table structure and removes all of the data.